# Square bullet in same font

Tags: fonts, symbols

How can I get the filled square bullet in same text font, assume the text font should be AGaramond, AdobeTextPro, etc. Note that I am using OTF type fonts and MikTeX 2.9, and dvips to generate the output.

PS: Hope this may not require MWE!!

Comment: I don't know how you use otf-fonts with dvips and I don't know what a "square bullet" is.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am using the script autoinst to convert OTF fonts to MikTeX compatibility...

Comment: Well then you are not using otf fonts, and you should have given a minimal example, to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This approach will work regardless of the font or engine chosen, by matching the current definition of `\bullet`.

BONUS: Works in all math styles.

EDIT: Added appropriate sidebearings.  REEDITED to make those sidebearings independent of the font.  That is, `\sqbullet` will literally occupy the same horizontal and vertical footprint as the corresponding `\bullet`.  The macro `\bulletolay` is merely a 2-color diagnostic to confirm this.

Finally, made `\sqbullet` into `\mathbin` class, to match `\bullet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\vcenterht
\newlength\halfht
\newcommand\sqbullet{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\SavedStyle()$}%
  \vcenterht=\dimexpr.5\dimexpr\ht2-\dp2\relax\relax
  \halfht=\dimexpr\ht0-\vcenterht\relax
  \kern.5\dimexpr\wd0-2\halfht\relax
  \rule[\dimexpr\vcenterht-\halfht\relax]{2\halfht}{2\halfht}%
  \kern.5\dimexpr\wd0-2\halfht\relax
  }}%
}
\newcommand\bulletolay{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle\sqbullet$\cr%
  \textcolor{red}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}
\begin{document}
$x\bullet\sqbullet\bulletolay$

$\scriptstyle x\bullet\sqbullet\bulletolay$

$\scriptscriptstyle x\bullet\sqbullet\bulletolay$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but the square bullet doesn't show as a font...

Comment: @MadyYuvi That is because it is not a font, it is an appropriately sized `\rule`.  Because one cannot be sure if the character exists within the font. I would expect that it does not exist in most fonts.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I just reedited my answer to make the sidebearings independent of the font, so no changes are needed, regardless of font employed.

Answer (score 1):

`EB Garamond` has a square bullet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\def\sqbullet{\char "25A0}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=\sqbullet]
\item This is a \emph{square} bullet in EB Garamond.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One might take time to note, even though the OP did not specify, that this square bullet is not matched in any way to the math mode `$\bullet$`.

Comment: @Bernard; Thanks, but I need to execute this in normal LaTeX not through XeLaTeX...

Comment: With an opentype font?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, exactly...

Comment: So you need to use `fontspec`, hence you have to compile with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`.